# PHP how determine behavior between two objects according SOLID principles

Tags: php, oop, solid-principles

I know this question will be considered as opinion based but I'm really stuck and some advices other approaches will be very helpful to clearly understand things

I am working on a shopping cart system that can contain both digital and non-digital products.

The non-digital ones can therefore be ordered in multiple copies, whereas the digital ones cannot.

How do you determine the digital nature of a product and force his quantity ? Here's how I was thinking of implementing the representation described above

```php
<?php

abstract class Products
{
    private $quantity = 1;

    public abstract function isDigital():bool;

    public function setQuantity(int $quantity)
    {
        if ($this->isDigital())
            return;
        
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }
}

class DigitalProduct extends Products
{
    const DIGITAL = true;

    public function isDigital():bool
    {
        return self::DIGITAL;
    }
}

class UnDigitalProduct extends Products
{
    const DIGITAL = false;

    public function isDigital():bool
    {
        return self::DIGITAL;
    }
}

$digitalProduct = new DigitalProduct();
$unDigitalProduct = new UnDigitalProduct();

$products = [$digitalProduct, $unDigitalProduct];

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->setQuantity(4);
}
```

This implementation could be considered acceptable in order to respect abstraction principles ?

Comment: Move the `setQuantity()` method into the subclasses. The implementation in `DigitalProduct` does nothing, the implementation in `UndigitalProduct` updates the property.

Comment: @Barmar as `setQuantity` is a common functionality why move it into subclasses ? is it clean to implement a method that does nothing ? If it's needed to move it, should it be declared as abstract in parent ?

Comment: Because the behavior depends on the class. Yes, it should be declared as an abstract method in the parent. Or you could put a default method in the parent, and then override it in just one of the children.